# optimising intervals in a histogram

Tags: optimization, histogram

I'm a complete newbie (not even computer sciencist) but since I started to learn about Python & programming in general I want to solve this problem to see how hard this kind of thing are to solve with programming. 
I have also no idea from mathematical point of view how hard is this to answer, whether it is easy few lines of code or needs some optimisation job done ??

Lets say I have a set of 35 'values' from 1 to 200.

I'd like to group them into 5 groups ('bins'), BUT I want **the same number** of 'values' for each group (bin). So **the chart will be like 5 bars of the same height**. So not sure it is still called a histogram. Anyway, the only problem is **how to calculate (optimise?) those intervals / transition points.** / bin widths. Is it hard to code that or not at all ?

I only get to the point, that **if there was only 2 groups (bins), the "transition point" is a median**. 
If there is 4 groups you calculate another two medians , for each of two groups. 
But I don't know what if there is 5 groups (bins) and if there is a better way to code it than calculating a median.

**Thanks in advance for your replies.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are probably more efficient algorithms out there for this problem than the one I am about to propose, but I feel that for a group of 35 values ranging from 1 to 200, this problem does not demand the most efficient and optimized algorithm. A straightforward, and understandable approach should suffice.

To begin, place 4 dividers evenly spaced in your list (this can represented by 4 values in a separate list indicating their indices). Then, set a variable, *altered* to true, and enter  your main loop: while altered, do logic. Immediately set altered to false (this will allow us to terminate once we reach our optimal solution). Now, still within the while loop, have a for loop that iterates from 0 to 3 (inclusive) that compares the heights on either side of each divider. While moving the divider either direction decreases their difference, continue to move it that direction, and set *altered* to true. Now allow the for loop to repeat for all dividers, and the outermost while loop to rinse and repeat the cycle until no better solution can be found.

EDIT: Here is some python code that attempts to do what I've explained above. You may want to adjust the compare_bins function to meet your criteria of what the most balanced histogram is (I've defined it as the minimal sum of differences between all adjacent neighbors).

```
list_values = [10, 27, 59, 177, 185, 195, 54, 151, 15, 26, 105, 22, 32, 179, 92, 1, 115, 129, 152, 124, 100, 134, 175, 1, 149, 178, 28, 51, 90, 69, 128, 96, 8, 18, 38]
edges = [0, 7, 14, 21, 28, len(list_values)] # 0 and 34 are the ends of the list, and we do not change

def compare_bins():  # scores the difference in the histogram heights
    global list_values, edges
    score = 0
    for bin_id in range(4):
        idx = bin_id + 1
        prev_bin = sum(list_values[edges[idx-1]:edges[idx]])
        next_bin = sum(list_values[edges[idx]:edges[idx+1]])
        score += abs(prev_bin - next_bin)
        print(abs(prev_bin - next_bin))
    return score

altered = True
while altered:
    altered = False
    for i in range(4):
        old_diff = compare_bins()
        idx = i + 1
        edges[idx] -= 1
        while compare_bins() < old_diff:  # try moving the dividers left
            edges[idx] -= 1
            altered = True
        edges[idx] += 2
        while compare_bins() < old_diff:  # try moving the dividers right
            edges[idx] += 1
            altered = True
        edges[idx] -= 1
```

Comment: thanks man, I will keep your post for sure and use it when I know how to code it ;-) I'm at the stage of learning basics (theory) and looking into the codes and manipulating it to have different outcomes. Can't write myself yet but I'll try to figure what you talk about. Maybe someone could write if thats a few lines ? Cheers !

Comment: What language are you intending to use? I could try to write up a quick mock up  of the code if needed if its a language I'm familiar with, or if you don't mind pseudo-code.

Comment: I've added the code to my answer. Note that you probably need to adjust the compare_bins() scoring function to your needs. I've tested it myself briefly and it seems to work, but I may be overlooking some local-maximum case. Either way, I hope this can solve your problem.

Comment: wonderful... thanks a lot ... I will study it and try to run it :-)

Comment: I thought you said you wanted 5 bars though, not a value-dependent 'n' number of bars? I may just be misunderstanding your original question.

Comment: Sorry if I was not very clear. I wrote: ****If there is 4 groups you calculate another two medians , for each of two groups. But I don't know what if there is 5 groups (bins)***** so I decide of number of bars, the intervals / transition points in this problem need to be calculated or probably better word: optimised automatically.. :-) ignore the post from this guy its irrelevant , cheers !!

Comment: so bars have same height but different width